# How to send the content in the json file to the frontend?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I need some guidance as to how can I display my json file inside a popup in my frontend. I have written some code in order to read the json file but I don't know how to send it now to the frontend or/and how to call it from the html file.

Here is code for the frontend:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>its4land</title>

    <style>

    .popup {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}


 .popuptext
                {
                    display: none;
                    color: black;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 100px;
                    left: 400px;
                    padding: 60px;
                    border: solid 1px #ddd;
                    border-radius: 20px;
                    background: #F0E68C;
                    width: 10%;
                }

        .popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s
}


@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup"  style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;">
             <img src="Boma_1_2/F16_20170316141116392_0001.jpg" onclick="myFunction(event)" alt="Boma" style="width:1000px;height:600px;">
             <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Vegetation</span>
        </div>

    <script>

function myFunction(e) {

       var x=e.pageX;   
       var y=e.pageY;   
       $("#myPopup").css({ left: x });
       $("#myPopup").css({ top: y });
       $("#myPopup").show();

    }
</script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Here is my json file:

```
{
"name":"vegetation",
"id":2,
"children":[
    {
        "name":"forest area",
        "id":3,
        "children":[
        {
            "name":"kakamega forest",
            "id":4,
            "children":[]
        },
        {
            "name":"cherangam hills forest",
            "id":5,
            "children":[]
        },
        {
            "name":"karura forest",
            "id":6,
            "children":[]
        },
        {
            "name":"loita forest",
            "id":7,
            "children":[]
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"plantation",
        "id":8,
        "children":[
        {
            "name":"sonag tree",
            "id":9,
            "children":[]
        },
        {
            "name":"acacia tree",
            "id":10,
            "children":[]
        },
        {
            "name":"kaffirboom coral tree",
            "id":11,
            "children":[]
        }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Here is my index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

fs.readFile('new_veg.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err; 
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
});


app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log("server running");
});
```

Comment: I want to display the names in the json file in the similar pattern. That is, on click I should see the inner names for example vegetation-> forest area-> kakamega forest etc...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will return any json data from express app on frontend.

```
const yourJson = require("new_veg.json");

app.get("/getMyJSON", (req, res) => {
    res.json(yourJson);
});
```

You need to call this route with ajax, for example.

```
jQuery.getJSON("/getMyJSON", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

All what left to do is to paste retreived data into any DOM element that you need.
Hope it will help.

Comment: Is this the exact ajax request that you have written? Can i just use it as it is?

Comment: Well, you can try, but I written this just as example.

Comment: `res.json(youJson);` should have an r in it: `res.json(yourJson);`

Comment: @Adder, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I have written this ajax call:      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery.getJSON("/getMyJSON", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
        }
    })

Comment: @Salman, You don't need to wrap it into another ajax call. ```getJSON``` is already performs it and will return loaded data in the callback.

Comment: Oh ok. Next i have a div element in which there is a popup as you can see in the code above. intially I have displayed "vegetation" on it. But now I want to display the names that are in the json file inside the popup. That is, after every click I should see the inner names for example vegetation-> forest area-> kakamega forest etc...

Comment: Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @Salman, I'm not sure if I understood that correctly, but... You can do ```map``` by names on the retrieved data and grab all the names that you need. Anyway, this is sounds like another question and requires more clarifications.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Salman, You can always vote up on a comment or on answer to say thanks, as well as mark answer as accepted.